# Best method to show count of the records? Separate table? MySQL query cache? Count from select query?

Tags: mysql, asp.net, database-performance, query-cache

I have a joblisting site created by using ASP.NET and DB is MYSQL.

In there users can put vacancies to countries by selecting them. And every job has its own category.  What I want to do is show the counter in front of each location and each categories.

I will normally do this by getting the row counter from the query using a left join.

So is that a good method considering the performance?

What if I maintain a separate table for store the counters. If user put an ad, counter will increment by 1 and if delete or expired then counter decrease by 1. Remember there millions of users putting ads at same time. Could this lead to a lock?

I also heard about MySQL query cache. I dont have any idea about this.

This site get many daily page hits. near to 2 million.

Or else is there a best method to do this? Remember I don't want to tell the exact records of the DB up to that point. Users don't care about that. But accuracy should be there for a particular time.

Answer (score 1):

Issuing a `left join` + `group by` query each time someone sees a country or a category doesn't sound like a good idea. It is very likely that this will lead to poor performance.

MySQL query cache may help a bit, but I wouldn't rely on it.

Storing counters separately will denormalize your data, which may potentially lead to counters being out-of-sync with actual data (e.g. if you modify job listings manually or through the code that does not update the counters).

How crucial is it for the counters to always be precise? I bet that it's not that important. Hence, I would implement an application-level cache (stored e.g. in [ASP.NET Application State](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bf9xhdz4(v=vs.85).aspx)), storing a counter for each country and each category. Wrap the cache in a class that will take data from cache unless it's been N minutes since it was last updated. Otherwise, first issue a database query to update the cache with current data (remember to surround this logic with a `lock()` or use another thread safety mechanism of your choice).

Comment: What you mean by surround this logic with a lock()?

Comment: See [lock statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). You want to make sure that two threads are not updating the cache simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

At 2 million queries per day, you may not yet be in trouble, but getting close.

The Query cache is *not* a viable solution.  Every write to the table invalidates *every* entry in the QC for that table.  Unless the number of reads is significantly more than the number of writes, the QC is a waste.

You say that the exact number is not critical?  Then I suggest:

- Have a separate table of counts.
- Have a background job recounting everything, but being careful not to hold any locks for long.  If you have replication, consider reading from a slave and writing to the master.
- The table would have only the category and count, making it small and cacheable (in the engine's regular cache, not the QC).

By pulling the counts out of the main table, the cuts down on the impact on the main table.

If you need further help, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and a `SELECT ... GROUP BY ...` that would generate all the counts.  This should give us more details about what you are working with, though that query may not be directly viable.